# Print console output to textfield Grails

Tags: grails

How do I print a console output to a g:textfield in a GSP using Grails?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips:

1. First, the tag name is g:textField, so an entire line looks like this: `<g:textField name="myField" value="${myValue}" />`
2. To send a value from the controller to the gsp page to fill out that field, you have to set `myValue` in the controller and send it in the parameter map
3. To print the contents of the textField to the console as one possible destination, you use `params.myField` to get the value inside your controller